# How stripe works with google pay & apple pay in react native

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments, payment, applepay, google-pay

I works with react native stripe, it's works buti don't know how money send from user to me, in normal stripe form i know the payment charging in my **stripe account**, but with google pay and apple pay where money will charging?, in stripe i account also or what, and i need image or any **Guide** for how payment works from user to end of payment process
**react-native version 61.0**
**tipsi-stripe last version**

Answer (score 0):

Neither Google Pay or Apple Pay will actually perform the charge.

Google Pay will securely share a user's payment credentials that you could then send to your Payment Service Provider for them to process the payment. So in your case, the payment processing should be the same as your non Google Pay process.